# Save data from all my .tex files to a global file

Tags: filesystem-access

I want to keep track of some info of my .tex files.

More precisely, I give an `id` (an integer) to my math exercises and would like to keep somewhere the maximal `id` already given (and maybe other info). The macro is just `\idExo{}`.

I would like also the macro to be executable on other people's distributions without causing bugs.

Here is my plan :

- Choose a specific hard-coded path OR write to the "texmf" folder
- Read the maximal `id` in the file if it exists
- If the current `id` is higher, replace it

So far, I am able to write to a file:

```
\def\writeToFile
{
\newwrite\myfile
\immediate\openout\myfile=\jobname.foo
\immediate\write\myfile{coucou}
\immediate\closeout\myfile
}
```

Is there something simplier or am I on the good track?

Comment: you are missing `%` and the `\newwrite` should be outside your macro so you only do it once (otherwise in classic tex you will not be able to write more than 12 or so times)

Comment: Thanks.
So, how can I close the writing? Do I have to tell it explicitly before `\end{document}`?